# Pandas: for all set of duplicate entries in a particular column, grab some information

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large Dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
     ID_Code    Status1    Status2
0      A          Done       Not
1      A          Done       Done
2      B          Not        Not
3      B          Not        Done
4      C          Not        Not
5      C          Not        Not
6      C          Done       Done
```

What I want to do is calculate is for each of the set of duplicate ID codes, find out the percentage of Not-Not entries are present. 
(i.e. [# of Not-Not/# of total entries] * 100)

I'm struggling to do so using groupby and can't seem to get the right syntax to perform this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but you appear to be referring to when values of `Status1` and `Status2` are *both* `Not`, correct? If that's the case, you can do something like:

```
df.groupby('ID_Code').apply(lambda x: (x[['Status1','Status2']] == 'Not').all(1).sum()/len(x)*100)

ID_Code
A     0.000000
B    50.000000
C    66.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. Could you help explain the breakdown of the apply function here?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sum` and a `boolean` mask:

```
df.filter(like='Status').eq('Not').all(1).groupby(df.ID_Code).mean().mul(100)
```

```
ID_Code
A     0.000000
B    50.000000
C    66.666667
Name: flag, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great inline solution! Came to the same but using more functions.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['ID_Code'],(df['Status1'].eq('Not'))&(df['Status2'].eq('Not')),normalize ='index')
Out[713]: 
col_0       False     True 
ID_Code                    
A        1.000000  0.000000
B        0.500000  0.500000
C        0.333333  0.666667



#pd.crosstab(df['ID_Code'],(df['Status1'].eq('Not'))&(df['Status2'].eq('Not')),normalize ='index')[True]
```