# Pandas: for all set of duplicate entries in a particular column, grab some information PART 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I recently asked a question on this set of data ([Pandas: for all set of duplicate entries in a particular column, grab some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614339/pandas-for-all-set-of-duplicate-entries-in-a-particular-column-grab-some-infor))

```
     ID_Code    Status1    Status2
0      A          Done       Not
1      A          Done       Done
2      B          Not        Not
3      B          Not        Done
4      C          Not        Not
5      C          Not        Not
6      C          Done       Done
```

Right now I have this code:

```
df.groupby('ID_Code').apply(lambda x: (x[['Status1','Status2']] == 'Not').all(1).sum()/len(x)*100)
```

that gives me this output:

```
 ID_Code
 A     0.000000
 B    50.000000
 C    66.666667
 dtype: float64
```

What I want to know is to do the same thing but given an extra column of dates. So to reiterate, I want the percentage of Not-Not for each ID_Code per day.

```
     ID_Code    Status1    Status2    Date
0      A          Done       Not     01-23-18
1      A          Done       Done    01-23-18
2      B          Not        Not     01-24-18
3      B          Not        Done    01-24-18
4      C          Not        Not     01-24-18
5      C          Not        Not     01-25-18
6      C          Done       Done    01-25-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in `Date` to your groupby:

```
df.groupby(['ID_Code','Date']).apply(lambda x: (x[['Status1','Status2']] == 'Not').all(1).sum()/len(x)*100)

ID_Code  Date    
A        01-23-18      0.0
B        01-24-18     50.0
C        01-24-18    100.0
         01-25-18     50.0
dtype: float64

# To get as a standard dataframe, add in `.reset_index()`
# df.groupby(['ID_Code','Date']).apply(lambda x: (x[['Status1','Status2']] == 'Not').all(1).sum()/len(x)*100).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.